# How does the definition of an integral from Riemann sum work?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

So, the definition is

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \Delta(k)f(x_k)$$

My question is about the limit.

Theoretically, it is *impossible* to reach infinity, as it isnt a number. So when we say limit as n approches infinity,

Is the exact area then only a theoretical value?

Comment: That's not really the definition. It's a limit alright, but over a more complex space of partitions than just a number going towards infinity. That aside, however, you question doesn't seem to differ from the same question about limits _in general_. Limits have a precise definition which mentions only finite numbers; the "$\to\infty$" is merely suggestive notation, not something you actually need to "reach" to apply the definition.

Comment: Are you familiar with the formal definition of a limit?

Comment: No. Think of measuring the area of a circle by taking points on the circle and then finding the area of the polygon. Clearly the polygon area is less than that of the circle, but if we choose our polygon carefully then the area must be close to that of the circle. So, you can view the circle area as a limit as $n \to \infty$. However, it is clear that the circle has an area which is not 'only a theoretical value', and using polygons is just one approach to computing the value.

Comment: @KSmarts, yes. For n > N, $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$, so this is the limit infinity definition. So ours means $|\sum - L| < \epsilon \text{for} n > N$, so it is saying the sum converges to that specific value?

Comment: Think of the Darboux sums as a way of obtaining the area, much as we can reach any real number by a sequence of rationals. (However, I find thinking this way to be cumbersome, to say the least.)

Answer (score 0):

No; let $a = 0, b = 1, f(x) = x$. Let $x_k = k/n$. Then

$$
\sum_{k = 1}^n \Delta_k f(x_k) = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{n}\frac{k}{n}=\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k = 1}^n k = \frac{1}{n^2}\frac{(n+1)n}{2} = \frac{(n+1)}{2n}
$$

and as $n \to \infty$, this approaches $\dfrac{1}{2}$. So is $\dfrac12$ only a 
"theoretical" value for this integral?

No, of course not! Draw the function we are integrating here; you'll see that the region being considered is a triangle, and the formula for the area of a triangle is probably one of the most concrete mathematical facts you know.

What the limit means is that, as $n$ grows large, the approximate value (given by the Riemann sum) gets closer and closer to the *actual* value of the integral.